# nginx + tornado for a cpu intensive server

Tags: nginx, tornado

I have a setup in which I use three instances of a tornado webserver(which does cpu intensive computation) and i have it listen on three ports. I use nginx to balance the load among the three ports.

1. This is an experimental setup so is there something obviously wrong with it?

What I am looking for here is not a solution to a problem; I just wish to know if such a setup might end up causing any kind of scaling issues in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it won't really scale beyond having it listen on one port to be honest.

A better approach would be something like I outlined here: https://github.com/chaselee/tornado-linode

The actual directions on how to set it up are in the Readme.

Hope that helps!